# Create replica of a folder structure

Tags: c#, directory

I have few folders like below structure:
c:\temp\project\folder1\folder2 (this directory is dynamic, I mean there can be more or less folder)

I want to create a shadow of this structure with additional 2 folders in each directory like

C:\temp\projectNew\folder1(under folder1 I want to create 2 more folders, Archive folder, and notprocessed)\folder2(under folder2 I want to create 2 more folders, Archive folder and not processed)

here is my try

```
var sourcePath = @"C:\\temp\\project";
var parentDirectorty = Directory.GetParent(folderPath);

var sourceDirectoryName = folderPath.Replace(Path.GetDirectoryName(folderPath) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, "");
var firstDestiDirectoryName = Directory.CreateDirectory($@"{parentDirectorty}\{sourceDirectoryName}new");
```

But don't know how to get other folders name and create Archive and NotProcessed folders in each directory.

Sorry for my terrible English.

Comment: Well, you need to get the folders underneath the main folder, then search those to get more folders etc and build up the tree until you get to the bottom of it. Since you don't know the depth of the structure you need to use recursion. I think there are methods and classes in the .NET framework already which can probably help you with this, I don't have time to look up the specifics right now but I'm sure you can search for it if you like. Also research recursion if you don't know about the technique.

Comment: So, phrasing your question differently; you have a "root" folder, in this case its Project. In that folder, there are folders, in each of these folders, and all of their children, you want to create more folders?

Comment: You got it right @WynDiesel

Comment: Sorry @WynDiesel I misunderstood your explanation. I want to create another directory. like project lets name new directory as projectNew and create all sub directory under that projectNew folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dump all available directories to string array:

```
string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories("C:\\temp\\project", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Then loop it:

```
for(int i = 0; i<directories.Length; i++)
{
    string newPath = directories[i].Replace("C:\\temp\\project\\", "C:\\temp\\projectNEW\\");
    Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
}
```

fortunately Directory.CreateDirectory automatically takes care of everything for you

Comment: I didn't downvote, but AFAIK SearchOption.AllDirectories only looks for immediate subdirectories, rather than being recursive all the way down the tree? At least that's what https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448(v=vs.110).aspx implies

Comment: @ADyson Just tested and it created tree up to 6 directories down (.NET 4.5.2)

Comment: Good to know, thanks. In that case, your code looks pretty neat, so have an upvote.

Comment: @MaKiPL it works great. I have tested it with 8 directories down. Thank you very much. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Use `GetDirectories` to get all directory and sub-directory path of a given path.

Next, for each path, add your folder into it.

```
public void XXXX(string path)
{
    string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    directories.ForEach(x=> AddNewFolders(x));
}

public void AddNewFolders(string path)
{
      var archivedFoldeer = Path.Combine(path,"Archive");
      if (!Directory.Exists(archivedFoldeer )      
           Directory.CreateDirectory(archivedFoldeer );
      //var notProcesssedFoldeer = Path.Combine(path,"NotProcessed");
}
```

Comment: Either I understood this question wrong or this is not the correct answer- It meant to be a shadow copy, therefore: c:\temp\project\ should be copied to c:\temp\projectNEW\. This answer combines every path it gets with "Archive". It means it does not create dictionary outside the 'project' but creates the 'Archive' directory inside it

Comment: @MaKiPL, I agree. The OP's question isn't clear. They mention a "copy", but from the example, it appears not to be a copy, but just creating new folders in the subdirectories, unless those two folders exist in the root folder?

Comment: @MaKiPL I understand the question from my perspective. Maybe I was wrong. Let the OP decide :)

Comment: @MaKiPL You are right, I wanted to create a new directory in this case my parent directory is project, i want to create another folder and name it as projectNew and create all sub directories that project folder has and create 2 more additional folders